# Sclera blood vessel enhancement and adaptive thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to enhance the sclera blood vessels after I have done sclera recognition on a color image of a 600x800 image from the UBIRIS eye database. My problem is that after I tried to follow this paper written on this exact problem my results don't match the ones from the paper, enhancement and thresholding don't give the necessary results, so I cannot continue developing my algorithm for sclera matching.

Here is the reference paper I'm trying to use: https://scholarworks.iupui.edu/bitstream/handle/1805/2096/Thesis_OneDoc_Thomas_FinalETD.pdf

You're going to find on pages 61 and 62 in the PDF the part which isn't working for me.

Here is the input image I start from:
[image: input]

Here is the segmented image giving back the sclera area:
[image: segmented image]

Finally, here are the images after blood vessel enhancement and adaptive thresholding. Already blood vessel enhancement doesn't look that good as in the paper, but the adaptive thresholding is totally wrong.

[image: blood vessel enhancement]
[image: adaptive thresholding]

Finally, here is my MATLAB code I tried to write according the paper I previously linked:

```
    I = rgb2gray(segmentedImage);
gaborArray = gabor([3,4,5],[0,90,180,270]); %maybe 0,90,180,270 or 0,45,90,135
[gaborMag, gaborPhase] = imgaborfilt(I,gaborArray);
f = zeros(size(I,1),size(I,2));
for i = 1:size(I,1)
    for j = 1:size(I,2)
        for k = 1:12
            f(i,j) = f(i,j) + gaborMag(i,j,k).^2;
        end
        f(i,j) = sqrt(f(i,j));
    end
end

maxh = max(f(:));

for i = 1:size(I,1)
    for j = 1:size(I,2)
        f(i,j) = f(i,j)/maxh;
    end
end

TH = 0.33;
[x,y] = find(f~=0);
hist = [x,y];
histH = histogram(hist,255,'Normalization','probability');
dataH = histH.Values;

thresholdsH = zeros(1,255);

%calculate sum minus constant for each case of T with absolute value and save into array
for i = 1:255
    currentH = 0;
    for j = 1:i
        currentH = currentH + dataH(j);
    end
    currentH = currentH - TH;
    currentH = abs(currentH);
    thresholdsH(i) = currentH;
end

[MH, thH] = min(thresholdsH);
thH = thH / 255;

B = zeros(size(I,1),size(I,2));

for i = 1:size(I,1)
    for j = 1:size(I,2)
        if(f(i,j) > thH)
            B(i,j) = 1;
        else
            B(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end

filteredImage = B;
```

Can anyone help me by finding the problem with this code? First of all, I'm not sure if I'm giving the right parameters to the Gabor filter bank for the 4 even orientations mentioned in the paper. After that normalizing by the maximum value of f is done because otherwise I get a fully white region already after blood vessel enhancement. Where do you reckon the problem is with this code? As far as I understand the paper I did it exactly as it is mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion here ,you can use firangi filter which is very good at this job
here is link to get code

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter/content/FrangiFilter2D.m

I have tried it on other image here is results
[image]

After this you have to do morphological operation to remove outer area.I would suggest `regionprops` in `matlab` for this purpose

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: I've tried with Frangi filter, but the result is only the outer area appears and no vessels are found inside the sclera area. Did you set any options for the filter or you just simply used it with a single argument of the input image?

Comment: as it mention while using firangi filter you have to alter parameters  as per your problem..Do change in options i believe it will work